# Best way to get notifications to Angular Client from an Azure hosted Web API

Tags: azure

Best way to get notifications to Angular Client from an Azure hosted Web API

I'm creating an app where users can interact on articles. The back-end is asp.net core 2 web api. Front end is nodejs Angular universal app. I've decided to host on azure.

I need to get user notifications from server to the client. So if an user wrote a document and another user liked it, the notification will be sent to the user that wrote it, if the user is running the site.

I know I can achieve this using SignalR or Socket.io, but I was looking for something that azure provides.

Is there anything in azure that I can use, such as Event Hub, Event Grid or NServiceBus where there's already a javascript client that works on the browser, listening on Events?

Answer (score 0):

hi best way notification is **azure web job with azure web hook**

using web job you can get notification to any devices

for more details please see

[enter link description here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/01/30/sending-asp-net-webhooks-from-azure-webjobs/)

Comment: Mine is an angular universal app. Is there any example for receiving notifications into javascript?

Comment: i'm  research on it once i done with it  i will inform you